# Как удалить задачу в JIRA?

Tags: jira

Создал случайно задачу в проекте. Руководитель не я. Как ее удалить? Или это только руководитель может делать?

Comment: Подойдите к руководителю, объясните ситуацию. Случайно - не приговор.

Comment: Ну-у-у, когда открываете задачу среди прочих действий "Edit", "Comment" и т.п. должно быть выпадающее меню "More" в конце которого действие "Delete". Если у Вас такого нет, - как вариант, полагаю, недостаточно прав.

Answer (score 3):

Кто имеет право удалять задачу настраивается в свойствах каждого проекта администратором Jira. Причем  это может быть и обычный пользователь (а может и Руководитель проекта не иметь такой привилегии) - все зависит от того кому эту привилегию дадут. Можно давать привилегии по проектным ролям, по группам пользователей, только автору, только человеку, находящемуся в каком-то групповом поле задачи, конкретному человеку с конкретной фамилией.
Нужно смотреть как в конкретном проекте настроены эти права.

Еще как вариант - не удалять задачи - а использовать специальный статус "Удален" или "Отменен" бизнес-процесса. Ну и третий вариант - просто переиспользовать эту задачу для другой проблемы.